# Pedestrian Detection in Java

Tags: java, opencv, tracking, detection

I'm trying to do some simple pedestrian detection in Java using OpenCV.
Here's my code:

```
SimpleBlobDetector blobDetector;
blobDetector.detect(mask, matOfKeyPoints);
org.opencv.core.Scalar cores = new org.opencv.core.Scalar(255, 0, 0);
org.opencv.features2d.Features2d.drawKeypoints(frame, matOfKeyPoints, frame, cores, Features2d.DRAW_RICH_KEYPOINTS);
```

This does a pretty solid job, but the bounding boxes I'm getting around the pedestrian are actually **circles** and I need **rectangles**.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the circles are built-in and there is no default flag to draw rectangles instead. See `DRAW_RICH_KEYPOINTS` [documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d4/d5d/group__features2d__draw.html#gga7d976d140eaaf3aa965eff127db8572eac22e71af97a4741038f2fc47437371b8).

However, since you already have the keypoint locations, you can write your own drawing function. The c++ version of `drawKeypoints` function is [here](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/05b15943d6a42c99e5f921b7dbaa8323f3c042c6/modules/features2d/src/draw.cpp). And below is a concise version of the new function that draws rectangles instead.

```
void drawKeypoints( InputArray image, const std::vector<KeyPoint>& keypoints, InputOutputArray outImage, const Scalar& _color)
{
    bool isRandColor = _color == Scalar::all(-1);
    std::vector<KeyPoint>::const_iterator it = keypoints.begin(),
                                     end = keypoints.end();
    for( ; it != end; ++it )
    {
        Scalar color = isRandColor ? Scalar(rng(256), rng(256), rng(256)) : _color;
        p=*it;
        Point center( cvRound(p.pt.x * draw_multiplier), cvRound(p.pt.y * draw_multiplier) );
        int radius = cvRound(p.size/2 * draw_multiplier); // KeyPoint::size is a diameter

        // draw RECTANGLES (actually squares) around keypoints with the keypoints size
        rectangle(outImage, center + Point(-radius, -radius), center + Point(radius, radius), color, 1, LINE_AA, draw_shift_bits);

        // draw orientation of the keypoint, if it is applicable
        if( p.angle != -1 )
        {
            float srcAngleRad = p.angle*(float)CV_PI/180.f;
            Point orient( cvRound(cos(srcAngleRad)*radius ),
                          cvRound(sin(srcAngleRad)*radius )
                        );
            line( outImage, center, center+orient, color, 1, LINE_AA, draw_shift_bits );
        }
    }
}
```